# SVN merge: Is there a way to avoid having "tree conflicts" flagged for identical files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse, merge-conflict-resolution, tree-conflict

This happens to me all the time when merging, and I'm really not sure why (I saw several answers detailing several possible causes) but the cause is not relevant for my question, because regardless of what causes "tree conflicts" on identical files in identical paths the result is always the same: nothing at all needs to be changed and the "conflict" can just be marked as resolved.

So every time I have a "tree conflict" I have to [checkout the source file if it's not already there,] use a diff tool like WinDiff (because being that a "*tree* conflict" no SVN client opens its diff tool, although both files are there), compare the two files to find out whether they are identical (they almost always are) and if yes just mark the conflict as resolved without making absolutely any change to "solve" the conflict.

Obviously this is very very time-wasting and it feels really frustrating and pointless.

So I'm wondering if there is any way - through some SVN switch or some SVN client or anything else - to make so that tree conflicts won't be flagged in cases where it's 100% sure that nothing at all needs to be changed in order to solve the conflict - like in the case of my example above.

**ADDED**: It would also be interesting for me to know how usual it is for people to get tree conflicts on identical files (BTW I'm talking about files that *nobody* has touched since I created my branch, neither deleted nor recreated nor modified nor moved nor anything else). So you are welcome to leave a comment if you experienced that.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but it would have been more constructive if you also bothered writing what was wrong so I could improve in future.

Comment: AFAIK Tree conflicts happen when the files are deleted at source or target, or when file meta data changes in conflicting ways. Files may be identical, but may not share a common ancestor from SVN's viewpoint (e.g., files being deleted and then re-created without any actual content changes).

Comment: In my experience Eclipse's SVN plugins haven't been especially reliable. Maybe your version of it re-creates files needlessly erasing ancestry information, which causes tree conflicts. I always use the command line client for merging and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Also: more recent Eclipse versions seem to be more stable in general (not sure about your specific problem though).

Comment: @davlet Thanks for the info, that's useful and I actually edited my question because now I'd like to figure out whether me and my dev team are among the few ones who get this problem on a regular basis, or it's quite common and people just put up with it. Although I know for sure that for us the cause is not that someone deletes and recreates those files, your reference to using the command line is interesting, I will try that to see if the frequency with which this nonsense happens decreases.

Comment: @davlet BTW nice inference that I'm using Eclipse and a plugin (Subclipse) since I had not mentioned it :D . It's the latest (Eclipse Mars) and it and its plugins are always up to date, at least according to the Help / Check for updates menu.

Comment: Just for the record, this problem is one of the main reasons why we decided to drop SVN and switch to Git, and although that's the only thing we changed and we still work in the same way as we did with SVN, now when we merge feature branches back into master no conflict on identical files is flagged any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you were down voted, but your question does lack detail and substance. You just kind of say "what" you do but do not really provide any details that could help someone answer the "why".  What you ultimately need to figure out is why you are getting the tree conflict in the first place and the only way someone can help you is if you provide details.

I would encourage you to read [this section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html) of the SVN book so that you understand why and when SVN flags a tree conflict.  I would also use the command line tools that are shown in the book to explore the details of the tree conflict.  Hopefully once you understand why you are getting the tree conflict you might know how to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem of my question but I disagree with your statement about it.
I have a decent understanding of tree conflicts. I did not intend to start a discussion about why tree conflicts arise and even less was I asking how to avoid them, and to be honest I thought I had made this pretty clear. I have left out details about my tree conflicts completely on purpose because it does not matter to me why they occur. All that matters is that the ones on identical files are a lot and I would like a way to have them not flagged (or even better, marked as resolved automatically).